# Instal Deluge on RPI3 Raspbian

Tags: pi-3b+, deluge

I have been trying to install deluge on my rpi. The internet connection is good but when I try sudo apt install deluge it does not find the package. Any ideas? I feel like the repo isn't available. I tried the deb file from the deluge website and that has not worked either. Using Raspbian 9 Stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the package is called **deluge-common**.

You can install it with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install deluge-common
```

You can search the repository for a package with the following command:

```
sudo apt-cache search deluge
```

This will return all packages with deluge in the name or description.

Comment: That worked, I had to run 'apt update' for apt to see the deluge-common package. Once I installed that I searched for deluge again and it was there! Thank you very much!